# multiple instances of one fragment class

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a viewpager that will contain a couple of pages, the thing is that all of the pages will look the same (just different data) so i've created a fragment class, and i'm trying to add to the viewpager adapter instances of that same class... but I can't..

**How can I make a viewpager that every page is an instance of the same fragment class?
meaning: same design - different data**

**Edit...**
I took the general code from here...
http://tamsler.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/android-viewpager-and-fragments.html

and twicked it a-little bit

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private com.example.trying1.PagerAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initPaging();
}

private void initPaging() {
    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    NoteFragment nf = new NoteFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("noteTitle", "A");
    nf.setArguments(bundle);

    NoteFragment nf1 = new NoteFragment();
    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
    bundle1.putString("noteTitle", "B");
    nf1.setArguments(bundle1);

    fragments.add(nf);
    fragments.add(nf1);
    this.mAdapter = new com.example.trying1.PagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vPager.setAdapter(this.mAdapter);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the code you are using to create the many `Fragment`s?

Comment: You can.  I've seen many view pager examples that do this.  In fact I think Google's own Fragment example does this.  Just instantiate a new object and add it.

Comment: I edited my question, please look at the code, and thanks for the quick answers...

Answer (score -1):

Ofcourse you can. Are you getting an error or the data doesn't update?

EDIT:

It also depends on how you coded the fragment, to accept as a parameter and calculate the page?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;    
private List<Fragment> fragments;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initPaging();
}

private void initPaging() {
    fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    this.mAdapter = MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Add 3 fragments
     for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
       addFragments(i);

    //Set adapter     
     vPager.setAdapter(this.mAdapter);
}

 private void addFragments(int i){
   NoteFragment nf = new NoteFragment(i); //Pass data to the fragment, so it can process it
   //You may pass it as a bundle if you wish
   fragments.add(nf)
}
```

//Adapter code

```
private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {  

           public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {  
                super(fm);  
           }  

           @Override  
           public Fragment getItem(int index) {     
                return fragments.get(index);
           }  

           @Override  
           public int getCount() {     
                return fragments.size();  
           }  
      }  

}
```

Comment: umm I edited my question, look at the code, I'm trying to load the fragments to the viewpager, so each one will be a page

Comment: Do you know how many pages (fragments) you want to add, or do you want to decide and add it dynamically. I did a similar project recently adding new fragments to viewpager dynamically.

Comment: Right now I know how many pages I want, maybe later I'll try to do it dynamically..

Comment: Added code, it depends on the fragment too, how do you want to accept and process to generate different output for different screen.

Comment: It's exactly like my code... but I've tried it, and it still doesn't work... It sais the problem is in the row with the inflater.inflate

`public class NoteFragment extends Fragment {
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Inflate the view
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_frag, container, false);
  TextView noteTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.noteTitle);
  noteTitle.setText(getArguments().getString("noteTitle").toString());
  return view;
 }
}`

Comment: I uploaded that specific file... 4shared.com/rar/p72N7bMg/NoteFragment.html  @dcanh121

Comment: I can't download the file. its 0 KB

Comment: Can you post the note_frag.xml file. Do you think there is a valid TextView in that file with id="noteTitle" ? Also, posting the error log would be gr8.